Is it suitable to use residual to assess and tune non-linear regression models?
In linear regression analysis, you would usually use residuals to assess model's fit and examine any potential bias/skewness, or to perform feature engineering based on it. Is it a valid approach to tuning other models as well, i.e non-linear regressors like GLMs, tree models like XGBoost?
